# Conversion failed error during trigger execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have created a trigger on the student table and when the dropped status is turned to true, I have to delete that student from any group he is part of and add him in another log table.
The studentid is varchar and when I run the trigger, it gives me an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int.

But I am using the studentid as varchar. So I am confused from where am I getting this error.

[image]

Trigger is below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DROPPED_STUDENTS]
ON [dbo].[students]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
if (Update(dropped))
BEGIN
    declare @stdid VARCHAR(50)
    declare @semid int

    select @stdid = inserted.studentid, @semid = inserted.SemesterID from inserted
    BEGIN
    IF exists (select * from inserted, groupmembers where groupMembers.studentid = inserted.studentid and groupMembers.semesterid = inserted.studentid and inserted.dropped = 'true') 
        INSERT INTO membersInvalidated (studentid, groupid, memberstatus,statusDate,SemesterID)
        select @stdid, groupMembers.groupid, 'DROPPED', GETDATE(), @semid from inserted, groupMembers where inserted.studentid = groupMembers.studentid and inserted.SemesterID = groupMembers.SemesterID;
        DELETE from groupMembers
        WHERE groupMembers.studentid = @stdid and groupMembers.SemesterID = @semid
    END
END
END
```

Comment: maybe `SemesterID` has type varchar? try changing `@semid` to varchar

Comment: please add your tables and some sample data, so hat we can reproduce the problem, a fiddle would also be nice

Comment: semesterID or @semid is int. and error is coming in the conversion of the studentid

Comment: You have a fatal flaw in your trigger, as you are not handling multiple (or zero) rows. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for the information. How can i loop through the inserted table to get all the updated rows and then put them in my log table 'membersInvalidated' one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`semersterid` is an INT, you are comparing that to `studentid` that is VARCHAR

```
-- existing code:
IF exists (select * 
           from inserted, groupmembers 
           where groupMembers.studentid = inserted.studentid 
           and groupMembers.semesterid = inserted.studentid -- HERE!!
           and inserted.dropped = 'true')
```

I'm not sure why you even need that comparison, but it invovles an "implied conversion" and when it fails to convert studentid to INT it is failing.

I suspect that you want compare `groupMembers.semesterid` with `inserted.SemesterID`. I would also encourage you to stop using commas between table names in the from clause; use explicit join syntax e.g.

```
-- suggested code
IF exists (select * 
           from inserted
           inner join groupmembers ON groupMembers.studentid = inserted.studentid 
               and groupMembers.semesterid = inserted.SemesterID-- HERE!!
           where inserted.dropped = 'true')
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a stupid mistake.

Comment: it happens to us all & sometimes you  just need another set of eyes to find it

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the incorrect join clause alrady mentioned, your trigger has a **fatal flaw**: it does not take into account multiple or zero rows in the `inserted` table. Triggers in SQL Server run *per statement* not per row.

- You need to therefore join `inserted` in both the `INSERT` and `DELETE`
- You should use explicit join syntax rather than the deprecated comma-join syntax.
- `UPDATE` does not tell you if the data changed, only if the column was mentioned in the `UPDATE` statement.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.DROPPED_STUDENTS
ON dbo.students
AFTER UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT UPDATE(dropped) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE dropped = 'true')
    RETURN;


INSERT INTO membersInvalidated
  (studentid, groupid, memberstatus, statusDate, SemesterID)
SELECT
  i.studentid,
  gm.groupid,
  'DROPPED',
  GETDATE(),
  i.SemesterID
FROM inserted i
JOIN groupMembers gm
  ON i.studentid = gm.studentid
 AND i.SemesterID = gm.SemesterID
WHERE i.dropped = 'true';

DELETE gm
FROM groupMembers gm
JOIN inserted i
  ON i.studentid = gm.studentid
 AND i.SemesterID = gm.SemesterID
WHERE i.dropped = 'true';
```

You can alternatively do the `INSERT` and `DELETE` in one statement, by using `OUTPUT`. This assumes that all rows to be inserted are also going to be deleted.

Note that `deleted` here refers to the rows being deleted in the `DELETE` statement, not to the outer trigger's `deleted`.

```
DELETE gm

OUTPUT 
  deleted.studentid,
  gm.groupid,
  'DROPPED',
  GETDATE(),
  deleted.SemesterID
INTO membersInvalidated
  (studentid, groupid, memberstatus, statusDate, SemesterID)

FROM groupMembers gm
JOIN inserted i
  ON i.studentid = gm.studentid
 AND i.SemesterID = gm.SemesterID
WHERE i.dropped = 'true';
```